# Taxi rates from San Jose Airport, Costa Rica (SJO) to Alajuela

Tags: airports, transportation, taxis, price, sjo

I'm flying into SJO and staying at a guest house 3 minutes away in Alajuela. I'm hoping to find what amount I should expect to pay so that I don't get overcharged.

Answer (score 1):

Airport taxis are usually expensive, as is almost anything you buy at an airport.

They are likely to price up a short journey: they won't want to wait an hour for a job just to take a $10 fare.

You could obtain contact details for local taxi operators, and phone them in advance for 'on demand' quotes (not booking in advance). Then when you have gone through immigration call a taxi "right away, I am waiting".

They won't want to take a booking in advance for such a short journey, with the unreliability of landing and immigration times.

Another way would be to use Uber, which operates in Costa Rica. But again, don't make a booking in advance. If you can, ask the airport taxis first, and if you don't like their price, call Uber, right in front of them.

Answer (score -3):

You can view the prices on Uber:

[image]

4000 CRC is about 7 USD.

Ride sharing is recommended if possible in countries where regular taxi drivers may be dishonest, i.e. most countries.